# Why might Chameleons die soon after being brought home?

Tags: death, chameleons

A co-worker mentioned they bought a Chameleon but after that weekend said it died. This week she got another one and said that it also died, this time within 4 hours of being brought home. Is this a common occurrence?

I'd like to know why these Chameleons may have died so quickly - specifically whether or not there are known common problems that may lead to a chameleon dying within a day or two of being brought home, assuming at the very least the basic care practices are followed.

Comment: I'm sure there are a billion variables that each could have had a small effect. Them dying that quickly though suggests that they weren't in good health to begin with. Did she get them from the same place?

Comment: @Carcigenicate yes, same place.

Answer (score 2):

I know that if you are getting an animal from a big chain pet store like PetCo or PetSmart within the first few days of owning it, it isn't an unlikely occurrence for it to die because these places treat animals so poorly. Another factor that goes into it is that especially if the car-ride home is long that itself can stress out the animal. But, another big cause of death after getting an animal from a chain or less commonly but still it happens with local pet stores but they can have diseases which is why if an animal is to be with another animal you should quarantine it.